# If I remove migrations files, will there be a problem?

Tags: django, git, migration

I'm a new in web developing .im in middle of project and my project for now have several DB model .i want put migrations files into .gitignore, if i remove all existance migration files from host server and then after any pull from git in host i using `python manage.py makemigration` any problem will be occure(i using git for transfer code from local to host)?is need to change anything in local too?(maybe need remove migration in local too)
the reason i want do this is : every time i want pull code to host i have a problem with migrations file and after `python manage.py migrate` telling me `x migration need to y migration file that isn't here` or something like this message.sorry if my question is unclear .

Comment: best practice is to commit migration files.Also  please be specific regarding what issues you are facing.

Comment: why not to take the your database backup and delete all migrations and do `makemigrations` on local; push it to your production and migrate. That way your local and production are in sync.

Comment: @xxbinxx . good idea . i will doing this today and replying result. thank you sir.

Comment: @mehdi do let us know what worked for you.

Comment: @xxbinxx : One of my friend that i ask him too in last day answered ask me let him manage this and sync migrations file for local and server . i think he switched on past git version that both migration was equal and then started to move forward . as he working this from his house i don't know what do exatly but now migrations files are sync Mr.xxbinxx . thank you.

Comment: @mehdi you are very welcome.